# jQuery UI Resizable: how to prevent it from stretching?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a widget based on jQuery UI's `resizable` (version 1.8.24) which is filled with items immediately upon being displayed, and can then be cleared and filled again based on user's actions.  It looks roughly like this:

```
<div class="dialog ui-resizable">
    <div class="dialog-header">…</div>
    <div class="dialog-contents">…</div>
    <div class="dialog-controls">…</div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 1000"></div>
    …
</div>
```

It is cast into a Resizable using this code:

```
myDialog.resizable(
            { alsoResize: myDialog.find(".dialog-contents"),
              minHeight: minH,
              minWidth: minW,
              maxHeight: maxH,
              maxWidth: maxW
            }).show().focus();
updateMyDialogContents();
```

If the widget was not resized manually yet, it grows and shrinks along with contents of `div.dialog-contents`.  This is undesired.  However, if any of the resizing handles were dragged, it starts behaving like I want it to, i. e. keeps its size constant regardless of what happens inside `div.dialog-contents`.

**How do I make it keep its size constant from the very beginning?**

I have noticed that `_mouseDrag` method of `resizable` sets `width` and `height` to their actual values in the DOM element's `style` attribute.  Normally I would set the `style` attribute myself immediately after rendering the widget, but it has a number of inner elements in `alsoResize`, so this does not work.

Is there a way to call `_mouseDrag` programmatically with zero coordinate deltas so the widget will think that a real `"mousedrag"` event was triggered?  If this was possible, I would solve this issue by simulating a mouse drag immediately after the widget was initialized.

I have tried things like

```
dlg.data("resizable").
    _mouseDrag(new $.Event("mousedrag",
                           { dragState: "end",
                             dragDeltaT: 0,
                             dragDelta: 0,
                             dragDeltaX: 0,
                             dragDeltaY: 0 }));
```

with different events with no apparent success (it throws an error because some attribute always seems to be missing).

**Edit 1**: jQuery version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have settled for this hack:

```
        var noStretchingHack = function (widget) {
            var contents = widget.find(".dialog-contents");
            var hDiff = widget.height() - contents.height();
            widget.css({width: "600px",
                        height: (400 + hDiff) + "px",
                        top: "0px",
                        left: "0px"});
            contents.css({width: "600px",
                          height: "400px"});
            widget.trigger("resize");
        };
```

I pass it as a callback to the contents updater function so that it executes right after the contents are filled for the first time.  I am not proud of myself and I would love to hear about a more elegant solution, if it exists for jQuery UI 1.8.24.